# Multi-core execution Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

> Hi there. Currently I am building a web scraper which is running not very fast. Could I manage somehow my spider to use other CPU cores or multiple same spiders to run in parallel?

BricoMarcheSpider

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import csv
from scrapy import FormRequest
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from bricomarche.items import Product
from datetime import date
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst

CATEGORIES = ['http://www.bricomarche.com/l/nos-produits/bricolage/outillage-et-equipement-de-l-atelier/outillage-electroportatif/perceuse-sans-fil-visseuse-accessoire-87.html?limit=90&p=1&solr_is_local=1', 'http://www.bricomarche.com/l/nos-produits/bricolage/outillage-et-equipement-de-l-atelier/outillage-electroportatif/perceuse-perforateur-et-marteau-piqueur-88.html?limit=90&p=1&solr_is_local=1', 'http://www.bricomarche.com/l/nos-produits/bricolage/outillage-et-equipement-de-l-atelier/outillage-electroportatif/meuleuse-rainureuse-accessoire-85.html?limit=90&p=1&solr_is_local=1']

class BricoMarcheSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'brico_marche'

def start_requests(self):
    # full path 
    with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            magasin_id = row['Id']
            if row['Id'][0] == '0':
                magasin_id = row['Id'][1:]
            formdata = {'city' : row['City'], 'market' : row['Brand'], 'idPdv' : magasin_id}
            yield FormRequest(url='http://www.bricomarche.com/bma_popin/Geolocalisation/choisirMagasin', formdata=formdata, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse, meta={'cookiejar': i})

def parse(self, response):
    for url in CATEGORIES:
        yield Request(url=url, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_category, meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']})

def parse_category(self, response):
    pos = response.xpath('//div[@class="store-details"]/p/strong/text()').extract_first()
    if pos:
        for url in response.xpath('//a[@class="view-product"]/@href').extract():
            yield Request(url=url, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_product, meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar'], 'pos' : pos.strip()})
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@title="Suivant"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_category, dont_filter=True, meta={'cookiejar':response.meta['cookiejar'], 'pos' : pos.strip()})

def parse_product(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
    l.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    l.add_value('id_source', 'BRMRCH_FR')
    l.add_value('extract_date', str(date.today()))
    l.add_value('pos_name', response.meta['pos'])
    l.add_xpath('brand_seller', '//td[@itemprop="brand"]/text()')
    l.add_xpath('price_vat', '//span[contains(@class,"new-price")]/text()')
    categories = response.xpath('//li[@itemprop="itemListElement"]//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
    # setting categories and family
    # check with category which has fewer categories to verify values
    try:
        l.add_value('prod_name', categories[-1])
        l.add_value('prod_family', categories[-2])
        l.add_value('prod_category1', categories[0])
        l.add_value('prod_category2', categories[1])
        l.add_value('prod_category3', categories[2])
        l.add_value('prod_category4', categories[3])
    except:
        pass
    l.add_xpath('sku_seller', '//div[@class="content-fiche-produit"]/ul/li/p/text()')
    # Réserver en magasin
    existing_stock = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(),"STOCK_PDV")]').extract()
    # Produit disponible en magasin text
    product_available =response.xpath('//span[@class="product_avaliable"]').extract()
    if existing_stock:
        l.add_value('inventory', existing_stock)
        l.add_value('available_yn', '1')
    if product_available:
        l.add_value('available_yn', '1')
        l.add_value('inventory', response.xpath('//div[@class="bg-white"]/p/text()').extract_first())
    else:
        l.add_value('available_yn', '0')
        l.add_xpath('available_pos_status', '//div[@class="fiche-items"]/div/p/text()')
        l.add_xpath('available_pos_date', '//div[@class="fiche-items"]/div/p/text()')

    return l.load_item()
```

> Basically this is my spider. In `file.csv` there are approximately 450 lines. If I have to scrape 100 products my requests are ~ 450 x 100 = 45 000 `GET` requests. The `POST` requests are used for cookies. Every item is added to my database. In my `settings.py` I use `DOWNLOAD_DELAY=00.5` and the other parameters are by default. When I tried with `AutoThrottle` on it triples the time. Some information for what I tested:

- 8 concurrent request with `AutoThrottle` - 82 minutes for 1000 products
- 16 concurrent request with `AutoThrottle` - 73.5 minutes for 1000 products
- 16 concurrent request without `AutoThrottle` - 22.4 minutes for 1000 products

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Could you be more precise, please?

Comment: I'd like to ask you the same question, actually. At the moment your post is really broad and doesn't show any sign of effort/research you've put into your question. What have _you_ done to achieve this? What code have _you_ written?

Comment: I posted my spider code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be using [scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Most of the advice in the docs for [Distributed crawls](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#distributed-crawls) can be applied for running on a single machine as well, except you would run your spider multiple times on the same scrapyd server.

> If you instead want to run a single (big) spider through many
>   machines, what you usually do is partition the urls to crawl and send
>   them to each separate spider. Here is a concrete example:
>
> First, you prepare the list of urls to crawl and put them into
>   separate files/urls:
>
> ```
> http://somedomain.com/urls-to-crawl/spider1/part1.list
> http://somedomain.com/urls-to-crawl/spider1/part2.list
> http://somedomain.com/urls-to-crawl/spider1/part3.list
> ```
>
> Then you fire a spider run on 3 different Scrapyd servers. The spider
>   would receive a (spider) argument part with the number of the
>   partition to crawl:
>
> ```
> curl http://scrapy1.mycompany.com:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider1 -d part=1
> curl http://scrapy2.mycompany.com:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider1 -d part=2
> curl http://scrapy3.mycompany.com:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider1 -d part=3
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for my late one. I set up my scrapyd. My scrapyd.conf is by default as written here https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html. I can't really understand the statement: Scrapyd also runs multiple processes in parallel, allocating them in a fixed number of slots given by the
max_proc
and
max_proc_per_cpu
options, starting as many processes as possible to handle the load.

Comment: `max_proc` is the max. number of processes that will run at once. `max_proc_per_cpu` is the max. number of processes that will run at once on a single cpu core.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is how to run 1 spider on multiple cores. Eg. the question is asking how to distribute requests and processing to multiple cores. Scrapyd is simply the same as executing `scrapy crawl myspider` so it adds nothing to resolve the problem. See: https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#how-scrapyd-works